# как мне в цикле вывести массив js в формате html

Tags: javascript, html, css

[1]: https://javascript.ru/forum/misc/77694-kak-v-cykle-vyvesti-massiv-v-html-i-sdelat-selected-ego-nulevojj-element-s-pomoshhyu-js.html вот ссылка тут почемуто нехочет правильно отображатся

Comment: пожалуйста перефразируйте и дополните свой вопрос

Answer (score 1):

```js
let mass = ["1","2","3"];

let b = document.getElementById("body");

mass.forEach(e => b.innerHTML += "<p>" + e + "</p>");
```

```html
<div id="body"></div>
```

Comment: это не мой вариант https://jsfiddle.net/BaNru/0z72a91u/3/  вот код который нужно вывести как <span> так и <select> подставив в них элементы массива

Comment: @jobananas по русски напишите что вам нужно...ничего ж не понятною. Пример я привел как делается вставка html в цикле...на ваш вопрос я ответил

Comment: korzinka.byethost9.com вот сайт нужно нажать на товар и там справа нужно вывести размеры под ценой пример как это выглядит сдесь garne.com.ua/p97075 я базу данных неиспользую вместо нее таблица гугл там размеры буду брать   вот делаю вариант в html формате https://jsfiddle.net/BaNru/0z72a91u/3/ мне нужно конкретно его вывести можете использовать в качестве примера мой вариант?

Answer (score 0):

Вы это имеете в виду? Динамическое создание HTML ? Суть всё еще не понятна))

```js
let sizes = ['s', 'l', 'x', 'xl', 'xxl']

let mama = document.querySelector('.product-sizes');
let select = document.createElement('select');
    select.id = "ProductSize";
    select.name = "size";
    select.size = "1";

for(let i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++){
  let span = document.createElement('span');
      span.className = 'product-size';
      span.setAttribute('data-product-size', sizes[i]);
      span.innerText = ( sizes[i] ).toUpperCase();

  if( i === 0 ) { span.classList.add('selected'); }
  
  mama.appendChild( span ); 
  
  let option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = sizes[i];
      option.innerText = ( sizes[i] ).toUpperCase();
  select.appendChild( option );
}

mama.appendChild( select );

/* Дальше кусок вашего кода, не трогал */
/********************************************/


var GlobalSize;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
 document.querySelector('.product-sizes').addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if(e.target.classList.contains('product-size')){
   document.querySelectorAll('.product-size.selected').forEach( function(element) {
    element.classList.remove('selected');
   });
   e.target.classList.add('selected');
   GlobalSize = e.target.dataset.productSize;
   document.querySelector('#ProductSize').value = e.target.dataset.productSize;
  }
 })

 document.querySelector('#ProductSize').addEventListener('change',function(e){
  document.querySelectorAll('.product-size.selected').forEach( function(element) {
   element.classList.remove('selected');
  });
  document.querySelector('[data-product-size="'+e.target.value+'"]').classList.add('selected');
  GlobalSize = e.target.value;
 })

});
```

```css
.product-details .product-sizes {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.product-size.selected:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.product-size.selected {
    border: 1px solid #fa6f57;
    background: #fa6f57;
    color: #fff;
}
.product-size:hover {
    border: 1px solid #fa6f57;
    color: #fa6f57;
}
.product-size {
    color: #1f1f1f;
    border: 1px solid #1f1f1f;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: auto;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    min-width: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-sizes"></div>
```

Comment: да именно это только нужно еще подсветить выбраные варианты тем цветом с примера и в спане и селекте

Comment: <><><> Добавил...

Comment: выбраный  селект не выделяется тем же цветом и не поцентру в спане размеры

Comment: Учебник HTML / CSS → http://htmlbook.ru/ ( `text-align: center;` ) и JavaScript → http://learn.javascript.ru/ (вероятно, вам будет полезно немного ознакомиться со всем этим, потом начать что-то делать)

Comment: я уже зделал ток это добавить и все

Comment: текст выровнял ток еще понять как select подсветить

Answer (score 0):

```
// Создаём глобальную переменную для сохранения в неё нашего значения, _согласно_ВОПРОСА_!
var GlobalSize;
var shoparray = ['s','l','x','xl','xxl'];


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

    var spans = '', options = '';
    // проходим по циклу. Этот код надо прогонять постоянно при загрузке товара!
    // Генерируем HTML
    shoparray.forEach( function(el,i) {
        spans += '<span class="product-size'
        if(i == 0){spans += ' selected'}
        spans += '" data-product-size="'+el+'">'+el+'</span>';

        options += '<option value="'+el+'">'+el+'</option>';
    })
    // Отрисовываем в документе
    document.querySelector('.product-sizes').insertAdjacentHTML ('afterbegin', spans);
    document.querySelector('#ProductSize').insertAdjacentHTML ('afterbegin', options);
    document.querySelector('#ProductSize').selectedIndex[0];

    // Код ниже будет работать всегда и его перезапускать не надо!

// Щелчок по элементам
// Вешаем клик на родителя, чтобы не вешать обработчик на кадлый элемент отдельно
    document.querySelector('.product-sizes').addEventListener('click',function(e){
        // теперь проверяем, что кликнули именно по необходимому элементу
        // (проверяем по классу), другие будут игнорироваться
        if(e.target.classList.contains('product-size')){
            // запускаем необходимые действия
            // Удаляем староый seelect (через цикл для надёжности)
            document.querySelectorAll('.product-size.selected').forEach( function(element) {
                element.classList.remove('selected');
            });
            // Теперь выбираем текущий элемент
            e.target.classList.add('selected');
            // Сохраняем в переменную согласно вопроса
            GlobalSize = e.target.dataset.productSize;
            // Меняем селект, ведь это надо, это подсказывает мой хрустальный шар требуется?
            document.querySelector('#ProductSize').value = e.target.dataset.productSize;
        }
    })

    // Событие на изменение select
    document.querySelector('#ProductSize').addEventListener('change',function(e){
        // Опять удаляем все старые выделения
        document.querySelectorAll('.product-size.selected').forEach( function(element) {
            element.classList.remove('selected');
        });
        // Добавляем новое выделение
        document.querySelector('[data-product-size="'+e.target.value+'"]').classList.add('selected');
        // Пишем в глобальную значение
        GlobalSize = e.target.value;
    })

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BaNru/0z72a91u/4/

Comment: да это оно остается только селект подсветить тем же цветом что и спан подсвечен (выбраный)

Comment: В CSS пропиши нужный цвет.

Comment: где именно в каком месте?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-color